# Service MessagingCommunication Exception - The End point is only for web socket requests

Tags: wcf, azureservicebus, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

Have a service bus queue where we are polling for the messages using the ServiceBus QueueClient/ReceiveMessage.

The service bus version used is 3.1.4 and the connectivity mode is https.

We are getting the following exception in one of the machines:

> Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingCommunicationException: The
>   server rejected the upgrade request. 400 This endpoint is only for
>   web-socket requests ---> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException:
>   The server rejected the upgrade request. 400 This endpoint is only for
>   web-socket requests ---> System.IO.IOException: The server rejected
>   the upgrade request. 400 This endpoint is only for web-socket requests

Unable to figure out the root cause of this issue as to why we are getting only in one specific machine the MessagingCommunicationException.

Comment: Are you mean that other machines could work as expected? Could you please provide some key code for us to locate this issue?

Comment: thanks. The issue was happening because of some firewall restrictions. This issue got resolved once the firewall restrictions was removed.

Comment: Please elaborate on the firewall restrictions as I am having the same issue..

Comment: In case anyone else has this issue, I have opened another thread here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42527865/azure-service-bus-messagereceiver-receive-web-sockets-error