# Azure Service Bus MessageReceiver Receive() web sockets error

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I am working with a c# program within my network and am able to post messages to an Azure Service Bus queue.  When receiving them, I get an exception on `MessageReceiver.Receive()`. The code and error is below;

```
MessagingFactory factory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(QueueConnectionString);

//Receiving a message
MessageReceiver testQueueReceiver = factory.CreateMessageReceiver(QueueName);

using (BrokeredMessage retrievedMessage = testQueueReceiver.Receive(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20)))
{
    try
    {
        var message = new StreamReader(retrievedMessage.GetBody<Stream>(), Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();
        retrievedMessage.Complete();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        retrievedMessage.Abandon();
    }
}
```

The error gets thrown on the 'using' line at

```
testQueueReceiver.Receive(...);
```

> The server rejected the upgrade request. 400 This endpoint is only for web-socket requests

I can't find anything on the web with the exception of one post which seems to suggest it is a firewall / ports issue. I have all the azure service bus ports outbound open (9350-9354, 80, 443) locally but there is a chance the 9000's are blocked at the firewall. Should it require these?  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated !

[Service MessagingCommunication Exception - The End point is only for web socket requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41672060/service-messagingcommunication-exception-the-end-point-is-only-for-web-socket)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed due to some proxy issues.

The account that the code was running under was an async service. I needed to log in as that account, open IE and go to connections (LAN) and remove the proxy checkboxes (detect settings automatically, etc).  Once this was done, the code bypassed the proxy and worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just wondering why don't you use `OnMessage` instead of polling the queue?

```
       var connectionString = "";
       var queueName = "samplequeue";

       var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queueName);

       client.OnMessage(message =>
       {
         Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Message body: {0}", message.GetBody<String>()));
         Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Message id: {0}", message.MessageId));
         message.Complete()
       });
```

Comment: This code is part of a CRM plugin.  CRM plugins only have a 2 minute TTL I believe. Whilst it isn't ideal for the subscribe pattern, we are having to essentially poll the queue.  I do however get the exact same error using your method.

Comment: Like you have said, you open port 9354 locally, but there is still chance it is blocked by a firewall. Can you try to open the port on the firewall ?

Comment: I have 9354 outbound allowed through the firewall and locally with the same error :-(

Comment: At this stage, if you can open all the ports from this list https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brunoterkaly/2012/02/07/azure-ports/ locally to see if it helps? And then close the ports that are not required. Cheers.